# Best practise for managing UI in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

In SpriteKit, I'm using SKNodes, SKShapeNodes and SKLabelNodes for all my UI. It works well for the small game I've made, however, one small interface such as a 'Game Over' prompt can consist of well over 100 lines of code, and that's merely declaring and defining node properties. All these prompts and other UI are declared in their own separate functions and are called when needed throughout the Game Scene, but I can't shake the feeling that there is a better practise to managing UI. Perhaps a class where I can call the 'getGameOverPromptUI' or 'getScoreLabel' functions? Would I limit such a class to only the Game Scene? or include UI for the Menu Scene?

Edit:

To clarify, a Game Over prompt consists of a faded background covering the scene, a rectangle as the prompt box behind the text, labels for the game over title, the current score, the highest score, a button for playing again, a button for going back to the menu etc.

The reason for the code being so large is every component is pretty much created like this

```
let gameOverNode = SKNode()
    gameOverNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenSize.height / 16)
addChild(gameOverNode)

// Faded Background    
let fadedBackgroundNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: screenSize)
    fadedBackgroundNode.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.6)
    fadedBackgroundNode.zPosition = 1
    fadedBackgroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: -gameOverNode.position.x, y: -gameOverNode.position.y)
gameOverNode.addChild(fadedBackgroundNode)

// Prompt Background
let gameOverGradientNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: gameOverGradientNodeSize, cornerRadius: gameOverGradientCornerRadius)
    gameOverGradientNode.fillColor = .white
    gameOverGradientNode.strokeColor = .clear
            
let gameOverCropNode = SKCropNode()
    gameOverCropNode.maskNode = gameOverGradientNode
    gameOverCropNode.addChild(helper.getBackgroundNode2(nodeSize: gameOverGradientNode.frame.size))
    gameOverCropNode.zPosition = 2
gameOverNode.addChild(gameOverCropNode)

// Title Label
let gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "")
    gameOverLabel.name = "gameOverLabel"
    gameOverLabel.text = "Game Over"
    gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: gameOverGradientNode.frame.height / 4 + gameOverGradientNode.frame.height / 8)
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 160
    gameOverLabel.fontColor = .white
    gameOverLabel.zPosition = 3
    gameOverLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    gameOverLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
gameOverNode.addChild(gameOverLabel)
```

Comment: 100 lines of code to display 'Game Over'? What's wrong with an SKLabel? Can you explain what those 100 lines of code are doing (or include the code with a comments) as it's obviously not just putting some text on the screen.

Comment: As a recommendation, you can manage components and states with GameplayKit to decouple and create models to have a cleaner, shorter, and testable code

Comment: @SteveIves Hopefully my update clarifies what I'm doing

Comment: @P3rry Thanks for the update. I don't think it's unreasonable to create a nice screen the way you have, but if you have a few such screens to create, why not create a separate function or class to which you can pass the necessary parameters(colours, text etc) and which returns a node created with all the information specified?